# Methods for accessing files outside root

Tags: php, file, directory, directory-structure

Hi all :D My file structure is as follow:

```
/site
  /public_html
    /1
      /2
        /3
          read.php
  /file
    file.doc
```

For security reasons, I moved my docs outside public_html folder.
Inside read.php, I am accessing file.doc via code `"../../../../file/file.doc"`
Are there other methods (shortcuts?) to access the doc? I call on a lot of files from many locations. This code is too long and easy to lose track on how many `../` I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your virtual host is rooted on `/site/public_html` you can shorten it a little by using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`; this should work for all scripts underneath the document root in the same manner.

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/../file/file.doc';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `ROOT` constant that points to the root:

```
# on read.php
define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

and then just call:

```
# anywhere else
include ROOT.'file/file.doc';
```